# Can I execute a query to call a stored procedure with parameters in JDBC with out having to pass the parameters externally

Tags: java, spring-boot

for example, let's say I have a procedure named **delete_all_rows_from_table**, Can I execute the below query using JDBC

```
 String query = "EXECUTE delete_all_rows_from_table('all')";
```

or must I do it in the below format?

```
  String query = "{call delete_all_rows_from_table(?)}"; 
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(query);  
statement.setString(1, "all");  
statement.execute();
```

it is important because I want to implement a controller that takes in a stored procedure as string and excecutes it automtically, and in that case I wouldn't know the paremeters that will be coming. hence my question

Comment: You really don't want to have an endpoint that directly exposes calling your SPs. This massively breaks encapsulation and leaks the implementation details of your data layer.

Comment: Have you tried calling stored procedure with hardcoded parameter 'all'? What was the result?